# What's the difference between tar -A and tar -r?

Tags: linux, tar

I read that tar -A means: add archives to the end of an existing archive; tar -r means: append files to the end of a tar archive. Do they not mean the same thing? Could anyone please explain the difference between these two?

Comment: There is no option names `-A` with `tar`. You seem to be talking about a vendor specific option from `gtar`.

Comment: GNU tar is a fairly reasonable assumption, given the Linux tag.

Comment: It would help a lot if people did write `gtar` when they refer to incompatible gtar enhancements. There are still UNIX platforms around that will not accept `gtar` options and this is primarily a UNIX portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tar -A` takes two or more tarballs and concatenates them:

```
tar -A -f tarball1.tar tarball2.tar
```

adds the contents of `tarball2.tar` to `tarball1.tar`.

`tar -r` adds files to a tarball:

```
tar -r -f tarball1.tar file1
```

adds `file1` to `tarball1.tar`, as a file inside it alongside its other contents.

Here’s a more detailed example:

```
$ touch file1 file2 file3
$ tar cf tar1.tar file1 file2
$ tar cf tar2.tar file3
$ cp tar1.tar tar3.tar
$ tar Af tar1.tar tar2.tar
$ tar tf tar1.tar
file1
file2
file3
$ tar rf tar3.tar file3
$ tar tf tar3.tar
file1
file2
file3
```

Note how we end up with the same contents in two different ways. If you used `tar -r` with multiple tarballs, you’d end up with the added tarballs inside the receiving tarball, as-is, not “unwrapped”.